# LinkedList push() method in JavaScript with a this.tail , unable to understand the reference by value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, singly-linked-list

```js
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class SLL {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }

  push(val) {
    let newNode = new Node(val)
    if (!this.head) {
      this.head = newNode;
      this.tail = this.head;
    } else {
      console.log(this.tail);
      console.log(this.tail.next);
      debugger
      this.tail.next = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
    }
    this.length++;
  }
}

let x = new SLL();
x.push('Hi');
x.push('Hello');
x.push('How');
x.push('Are');
x.push('You');
x.push('Man');
```

Doubt:
After the 2nd push('Hello'), the tail is assigned with the newNode "this.tail = newNode" under else part. But in the 3rd push "push('How')" how the this.tail is still referencing the this.head.

I have done console.log of both "this.tail" and "this.tail.next".The output shows fresh node. Am not able to understand how this still reference to the this.head.

[image]

[image]

Thanks for the answers!

Usecase 1:

```
let l = { a : 1}
let o;
let p;

o = l;
p = o;

p.a = 2;

console.log("l",l);
console.log("o",o);
console.log("p",p);

p = { a:10};


console.log("l",l);
console.log("o",o);
console.log("p",p);
```

when p = {a:10} a new memory space is created right?

Now the link is broken form "p" to "o" right?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question.`this.tail` is always the node that was added by the previous call to `x.push()`, it's not `this.head`.

Comment: But when we check the "x" variable the head has a reference to the next followed by multiple nodes, which in return looks like a tree.  But the link between the head and tail is cut after the 3rd push is what am thinking. Am not able to understand how still this reference is maintained.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated new image of value "x"

Comment: Why would that cut the link? Each node has a link to the next one, that's what makes it a linked list.

Comment: My question is that in "else" if the "this.tail = newNode" then the reference is broken correct? If yes then how the "x" has all the nodes linked.

Comment: Look at the line *before* that. It creates the chain because it's updating the old tail to point to the new node in its `next` property.

Comment: If you see my screen shot it shows the ".next" value is null and the "this.tail" is a new node.

Comment: Each time you call `push()` it adds the new node node after the old tail, then updates tail to refer to the new node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254306/discussion-between-srujan-r-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

The `head` references the *first* node in the list, but that first node will get its `next` property updated when a second node is added to the list. We can "see" the tail node from the `head` node by following the `next` chain.

It may help to visualise this:

When `x = new SLL()` has executed, we can picture it as follows:

```
 x
 ↓
┌─────SLL────┐
│ head: null │
│ tail: null │
│ length: 0  │
└────────────┘
```

When `x.push('Hi');` is executed, `newNode` is created:

```
                    newNode
                     ↓
 x                 ┌─────Node────┐
 ↓                 │ val: 'Hi'   │
┌─────SLL────┐     │ next: null  │
│ head: null │     └─────────────┘
│ tail: null │
│ length: 0  │
└────────────┘
```

Then the `if` block is entered, where both `this.head` and `this.tail` are made to reference that new node, and finally the list's length property is updated:

```
                    newNode
                     ↓
 x                 ┌─────Node────┐
 ↓             ┌──►│ val: 'Hi'   │
┌─────SLL────┐ │ ┌►│ next: null  │
│ head: ───────┘ │ └─────────────┘
│ tail: ─────────┘
│ length: 1  │
└────────────┘
```

Now to the main program again, where `x.push('Hello');` is executed. Again a new node is created:

```
                                        newNode
                                         ↓
 x                 ┌─────Node────┐     ┌─────Node────┐
 ↓             ┌──►│ val: 'Hi'   │     │ val: 'Hello'│
┌─────SLL────┐ │ ┌►│ next: null  │     │ next: null  │
│ head: ───────┘ │ └─────────────┘     └─────────────┘
│ tail: ─────────┘
│ length: 1  │
└────────────┘
```

This time the `else` block is entered, where `this.tail.next = newNode;` is executed. It updates the `next` property of the node that `this.tail` references:

```
                                        newNode
                                         ↓
 x                 ┌─────Node────┐     ┌─────Node────┐
 ↓             ┌──►│ val: 'Hi'   │ ┌──►│ val: 'Hello'│
┌─────SLL────┐ │ ┌►│ next: ────────┘   │ next: null  │
│ head: ───────┘ │ └─────────────┘     └─────────────┘
│ tail: ─────────┘
│ length: 1  │
└────────────┘
```

This was an important step: the linked list was extended by mutating a `next` property, which is happening at a node that also the `head` property references, and explains why you can "see" that extended list by looking at `head`.

In that `else` block the next statement, `this.tail = newNode;` updates the `tail` property of the linked list instance, and finally the length property is updated:

```
                                        newNode
                                         ↓
 x                 ┌─────Node────┐     ┌─────Node────┐
 ↓             ┌──►│ val: 'Hi'   │ ┌──►│ val: 'Hello'│
┌─────SLL────┐ │   │ next: ────────┘ ┌►│ next: null  │
│ head: ───────┘   └─────────────┘   │ └─────────────┘
│ tail: ─────────────────────────────┘
│ length: 2  │
└────────────┘
```

This process continues with the addition of the next word. Every `push` will mutate the `next` property of the tail node and make it reference a new node.

I hope this clarifies why `head` can "see" the changes that are made to the list as you push new elements at its end.

Comment: Thanks for the images, 
But in the last step the "this.tail" is assigned with a new memory space  to the "newNode" am I correct?

Comment: When "=" equal operator is given to the variable not an object then new memory space is created am I right?

Comment: New memory (represented as boxes in the diagrams) is allocated when `new` is executed. `=` is assigning a reference to that memory. The `=` operator does not allocate new memory.

Comment: I have attached a new use case , where on assigning the value to "p" the new memory location is added. please refer the question. correct me if am wrong. Thanks

Comment: `{}` is short notation for `new Object()`. The memory allocation happens there. The assignment is merely giving a variable a reference to that memory.

Comment: But your extension of your question with multiple questions makes your question unsuitable and will attract votes to be closed. A question on Stack Overflow should be **one** question, not a blog with follow up questions. If you have a new question, I suggest you make it a new post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254307/discussion-between-srujan-r-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0):

**Linked** list implementation with **Tail address pointer**

```js
class Node {
  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
    this.tail;
  }

  insert(value) {
    // create object of node class
    let newNode = new Node();

    if (!this.root) {
      newNode.value = value;
      this.root = newNode;
      this.tail = this.root;
      return;
    }

    let current = this.tail;
    //assign value to newNode
    newNode.value = value;

    current.next = newNode;
    //update the tail to newly inserted Node address
    this.tail = current.next;
  }

  //   To print all nodes
  printAllNodes() {
    let current = this.root;
    while (current != null) {
      console.log(current.value);
      current = current.next;
    }
  }
}

let list = new SinglyLinkedList();

list.insert(5);
list.insert(10);
list.insert(15);
list.insert(20);
list.insert(25);

list.printAllNodes();

// console.log(list.root);
```

Comment: Please check this solution.

Comment: ok if it works for you then please if you like then you may accept my answer and upvote it.

Comment: My question is that in "else" if the "this.tail = newNode" then the reference is broken correct? If yes then how the "x" has all the nodes linked.

Comment: yes if we do this.tail = newNode then it will have reference of new node class object only. Not about the this.tail reference which has references so, firstly we store reference of this.tail in one address then we have reference of this.tail object in one address called temp (just to say) then we assign this.tail = temp because temp has address of  current node.

Comment: Posting code that works is not an answer to the question "how the this.tail is still referencing the this.head".